# How do I make Cloudformation reprocess a template using a macro when parameters change?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have a Cloudformation template that uses a custom Macro to generate part of the template. The lambda for the Macro uses template parameters (via the `templateParameterValues` field in the incoming event) to generate the template fragment.

When I change the Cloudformation Stack's parameters, I get an error:

> The submitted information didn't contain changes. Submit different information to create a change set.

If I use the CLI I get a similar error:

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the UpdateStack operation: No updates are to be performed.

The parameters I am changing are only used by the Macro, not the rest of the template.

How can I make Cloudformation reprocess the template with the macro when I update these parameters?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: @Daniel777 After working with AWS Support I learned that you must supply the template again. Even if it is the same exact template it will cause the macros to be reprocessed.

Comment: Thank you! I think you should post this information as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working with AWS Support I learned that you must supply the template again in order for the macro to be re-processed.

Even if it is the same exact template it will cause the macros to be reprocessed.

You can do this via the Console UI (by uploading the template file again) or the CLI (by passing the template / template URL again).

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this when using the count macro to create instances.

I found i was able to modify just the parameters used just by the macro by moving that part of the template to a nested stack and passing the parameters through.
It does involve a bit more work to setup by having the separate stacks, but it did allow me to modify just the parameters of the parent stack how i wanted.